# Set of polynomials of degree less than $N$ that have value $0$ in $x=1$ as vector space?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

How can I prove that *all* polynomials of degree less than $N$ that have value $0$ in $x=1$ are writable in this form?
\begin{equation}
p(x) = a_1 (x-1) + a_2 (x-1)^2 \dots + a_{N-1} (x-1)^{N-1}
\end{equation}
and so the set of polynomials of the question constitute a vector space of dimension $N-1$ (other properties are self-evident)? Of course $p(x)$ are polynomial and $p(1)=0$, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: need to show closure under vector addition and scalar multiplication. which is not hard

Comment: Because $p(x)$ is basically the set of all (polynomial of degree $\leq N-2$) multiples of $(x-1)$, once you factorize $(x-1)$ out of that expression. You know that for a polynomial $p$, $x-1$ divides $p$ if and only if $p(1) = 0$, by the remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic steps:

- Prove that your set of polynomials is a vector space through the axioms
- Notice that your set is **strictly** included in the vector space of all the polynomial with degree at most $N-1$, so it has dimension at most $N-1$
- Notice that $(x-1)^k$ belongs to your set for $k=1,2,\dots,N-1$ and that they are linearly independent
- Profit

Comment: You proved that the maximum possible dimension is N-1 and the minimum possible dimension is N-1. Charming. But I edited to spent some words about third point, at first glance it was not self evident to me.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro In these cases, you should write a separate answer (così magari ti prendi anche un po' di punti)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can express $p$ explicitly as
$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{p^{(k)}(1)}{k!}(x-1)^k$$
which you can prove by induction on $N$. Now since $p(0) = 0$ we get
$$p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{p^{(k)}(1)}{k!}(x-1)^k$$
which is your desired form with $a_k = \frac{p^{(k)(1)}}{k!}$.